# Extract personal information about a person from a list of documents and summarize it

Tags: natural-language-processing

I need to extract personal information about a person from a list of documents and summarize it to the user. If there are 2 people with the same name, the correct person should be identified. If the person has a nickname, that also needs to be identified. The input to the program can be the name of the person, address, organization name etc.
I have extracted named entities like person, org, location etc from the text using NLTK library. 
The output after extracting the named entities is mentioned below,

[('Michael', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Joseph', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Jackson', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('was', 'VBD', 'O'), ('born', 'VBN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('Gary', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Indiana', 'NNP', 'B-GPE')....

Now, I want to extract relationships between those entities.

Comment: Hello Amey. You don't ask a question here, just state a project goal. No-one here is going to do your whole project for you, so please make it clear what part of your project you want to ask about. Also please explain what relevant knowledge you already have so that people don't waste their time writing up descriptions that you do not need.

Comment: hi @NeilSlater , I have edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html has information on your query. Please start and go all the way to "6   Relation Extraction". Hope atleast this points you in the right direction.